# Backbone JS How to add a new model to a view to automaticlly re-render template

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I would like to attach a new model to a view and have the view re-render. I'm able to render the view in the first place, but I'm having trouble changing the data in that view to a new model.

```
my_model_1 = Backbone.Model.extend({});
my_model_2 = Backbone.Model.extend({});

my_view = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize : function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.model.bind('change', this.render);
    },

    render : function(){

    }
});

var view_instance = new my_view({ model: my_model_1 });

//Template gets rendered


try{
    view_instance.changeModel(my_model_2);
}catch(e){console.log(e)};
try{
    view_instance.set(my_model_2);
}catch(e){console.log(e)};
try{
    view_instance.fetch(my_model_2);
}catch(e){console.log(e)};
try{
    view_instance.model = my_model_2;
}catch(e){console.log(e)};  

//Template should get updated with data from model 2
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `change` event if fired when the data in your model has changed, in your case your view isn't "rerenering" because the data of it's model hasn't changed rather you just switched models. What you can do is manually [trigger](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-change) the change event after switching your view's model or call it's `render` method

For example

```
view_instance.model = my_model_2;
my_model_2.change();
```

Comment: I've now resolved the issue, and it was largely down to your answer although in the end, it turned out to be more of a scoping issue (as well as being related to your suggestion). I ended up making a window.model variable and setting that to my_model_1, then running:
var view_instance = new my_view({ model: window.model });  Then later, I ran: window.model.set(my_model_2), and this triggered the "change" you refer to, which updated my view. Many thanks! You were perfectly correct!